# TikZ Matrix Figure, Hiding Nodes, and Formatting Issues

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, nodes, tikz-matrix, crop

I'm trying to show the evolution of a cube-like structure when certain nodes are removed. Here is my initial diagram:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}

% AMS Math Packages

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Font Settings

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[kerning,spacing,babel,final]{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,matrix}
\tikzset{
    >=stealth,
    auto,
    font=\scriptsize,
    point/.style={circle,draw,very thick,align=center,
                  anchor=center},
    Point/.style={double,circle,draw,very thick,align=center,
                  anchor=center},
    transform shape,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=0.5cm,column sep=1.25cm] {
        &
        \node (1) [point] {$110$};
        & &
        \node (2) [point] {$010$}; \\
        \node (3) [Point] {$111$};
        & &
        \node (4) [point] {$011$};
        & \\ &
        \node (5) [point] {$100$};
        & &
        \node (6) [point] {$000$}; \\
        \node (7) [point] {$101$};
        & &
        \node (8) [point] {$001$};
        & \\
    };
    \path[solid]
        (1) edge [loop above,very thick] (1)
        (2) edge [loop above,very thick] (2)
        (3) edge [loop above,very thick] (3)
        (4) edge [loop above,very thick] (4)
        (5) edge [loop below,very thick] (5)
        (6) edge [loop below,very thick] (6)
        (7) edge [loop below,very thick] (7)
        (8) edge [loop below,very thick] (8)
        (1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
            minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (2)
        (1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (3)
        (2) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (4)
        (2) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
            minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (6)
        (3) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
            minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (4)
        (3) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
            minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (7)
        (4) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
            minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (8)
        (6) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (8)
        (7) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
            minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (8)
        ;
    \path[dotted]
        (1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
            minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (5)
        (5) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
            minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (6)
        (5) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (7)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following image:

[image: initial-state]

Now, I used this as a template to work off of, and in essence removed the nodes: 2,5,6 and 8 (and their respective edges):

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}

% AMS Math Packages

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Font Settings

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[kerning,spacing,babel,final]{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,matrix}
\tikzset{
    >=stealth,
    auto,
    font=\scriptsize,
    point/.style={circle,draw,very thick,align=center,
                  anchor=center},
    Point/.style={double,circle,draw,very thick,align=center,
                  anchor=center},
    transform shape,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=0.5cm,column sep=1.25cm] {
        &
        \node (1) [point] {$110$};
        & & & \\
        %\node (2) [point] {$010$}; \\
        \node (3) [Point] {$111$};
        & &
        \node (4) [point] {$011$};
        & \\ &
        % \node (5) [point] {$100$};
        & & & & \\
        %\node (6) [point] {$000$}; \\
        \node (7) [point] {$101$};
        & &
        %\node (8) [point] {$001$};
        & & \\
    };
    \path[solid]
        (1) edge [loop above,very thick] (1)
        %(2) edge [loop above,very thick] (2)
        (3) edge [loop above,very thick] (3)
        (4) edge [loop above,very thick] (4)
        %(5) edge [loop below,very thick] (5)
        %(6) edge [loop below,very thick] (6)
        (7) edge [loop below,very thick] (7)
        %(8) edge [loop below,very thick] (8)
        %(1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (2)
        (1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (3)
        %(2) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (4)
        %(2) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (6)
        (3) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
            minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (4)
        (3) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
            minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (7)
        %(4) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (8)
        %(6) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (8)
        %(7) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (8)
        ;
    \path[dotted]
        %(1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (5)
        %(5) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (6)
        %(5) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (7)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following result:

[image: successor state]

What's strange is that the distance between node and formatting seems off, and also there's a whole swath of extra whitespace on the right side of the figure.

What I'd like is to have essentially the dimensions and everything unchanged from the first figure but to simply hide the nodes and edges and leave everything else unchanged. Dimensions between the nodes labeled 111 and 101 should be unchanged, and all the remaining labels should also be left as they originally were. I'd also like to get rid of that whole mess of whitespace so that I can include them easily in presentations and in a document and not have to take into account all of the extra space on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `nodes` have a nonzero size and these further space out the diagram.  You can botch a fix by keeping the `100` node but making it invisible.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% AMS Math Packages

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Font Settings

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[kerning,spacing,babel,final]{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,matrix}
\tikzset{
    >=stealth,
    auto,
    font=\scriptsize,
    point/.style={circle,draw,very thick,align=center,
                  anchor=center},
    Point/.style={double,circle,draw,very thick,align=center,
                  anchor=center},
    transform shape,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=0.5cm,column sep=1.25cm] {
        &
        \node (1) [point] {$110$};
        & &
%       \node (2) [point] {$010$}; 
        \\
        \node (3) [Point] {$111$};
        & &
        \node (4) [point] {$011$};
        & \\ &
        \node (5) [point,opacity=0] {\phantom{$000$}};
        & &
%        \node (6) [point] {\phantom{$000$}};
        \\
        \node (7) [point] {$101$};
        & &
        %\node (8) [point] {$001$};
        & \\
    };
    \path[solid]
        (1) edge [loop above,very thick] (1)
        %(2) edge [loop above,very thick] (2)
        (3) edge [loop above,very thick] (3)
        (4) edge [loop above,very thick] (4)
        %(5) edge [loop below,very thick] (5)
        %(6) edge [loop below,very thick] (6)
        (7) edge [loop below,very thick] (7)
        %(8) edge [loop below,very thick] (8)
        %(1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (2)
        (1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (3)
        %(2) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (4)
        %(2) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (6)
        (3) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
            minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (4)
        (3) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
            minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (7)
        %(4) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (8)
        %(6) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (8)
        %(7) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (8)
        ;
    \path[dotted]
        %(1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (5)
        %(5) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
        %    minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (6)
        %(5) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (7)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=0.5cm,column sep=1.25cm] {
        &
        \node (1) [point] {$110$};
        & &
        \node (2) [point] {$010$}; \\
        \node (3) [Point] {$111$};
        & &
        \node (4) [point] {$011$};
        & \\ &
        \node (5) [point] {$100$};
        & &
        \node (6) [point] {$000$}; \\
        \node (7) [point] {$101$};
        & &
        \node (8) [point] {$001$};
        & \\
    };
    \path[solid]
        (1) edge [loop above,very thick] (1)
        (2) edge [loop above,very thick] (2)
        (3) edge [loop above,very thick] (3)
        (4) edge [loop above,very thick] (4)
        (5) edge [loop below,very thick] (5)
        (6) edge [loop below,very thick] (6)
        (7) edge [loop below,very thick] (7)
        (8) edge [loop below,very thick] (8)
        (1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
            minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (2)
        (1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (3)
        (2) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (4)
        (2) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
            minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (6)
        (3) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
            minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (4)
        (3) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
            minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (7)
        (4) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
            minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (8)
        (6) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (8)
        (7) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
            minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (8)
        ;
    \path[dotted]
        (1) [<->,very thick] edge node[above left, pos=0.4,
            minimum size=0pt] {$B$} (5)
        (5) [<->,very thick] edge node[above right, pos=0.75,
            minimum size=0pt] {$A$} (6)
        (5) [<->,very thick] edge node[above, minimum size=0pt] {$C$} (7)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So should I make all of the unwanted nodes invisible in that fashion or just that one?

Comment: @GregoryGelfond If you make the `010` or `000` nodes invisible then the `tikzpicture` becomes wider, if you make the `001` node invisible it has no effect on the spacing.  The crucial issue is that the third row of the matrix with `100` and `000` is shorter by the size of a node, so making the `100` node invisible adds the necessary vertical bump without making the `tikzpicture` itself wider.

Comment: Got it. What about the extra whitespace to the right of the figure? Is that an artifact of the nodes being removed as well?

Comment: @GregoryGelfond ah, hadn't noticed that.  There are a few rows with 3 `&` in them, if you remove the last `&` from each row it vanishes - for this new diagram you only need a matrix which is three columns wide so the fourth column also just adds white space to widen the `tikzpicture`.